# CSS animated hamburger icon and remove class on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

**I want to achieve 2 things when in responsive small screen size:**

1. Create a onclick CSS animated 'hamburger' icon into a cross icon (now it is just a fadeIn/Out effect).
2. Remove class on scroll event so cross icon turns back in default hamburger icon.

I'm now using svg images for the nav-btn.

I know that i have to add a removeClass action on the scroll event, but tried some different things, but my JS-skills aren't that good.

Hope there is someone that can help or guide me threw this either the one or the other.

[**Here the FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/g808a3q9/1/)

**Screenshots:**

[image]
[image]
**Cross need to changes back in hamburger icon on scroll:**

[image]

**Html:**

```
<header>
<nav>
    <div class="col-nav">
        <a href="#" class="nav-btn"></a>
        <a href="#" class="home">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li class="col-nav"><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
        <li class="col-nav"><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        <li class="col-nav"><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
$('.nav-btn').click(function() {
    $('nav ul').fadeToggle(300);
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
})
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav ul').hide(); }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add $('.nav-btn').removeClass('open');

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('nav ul').hide();
        $('.nav-btn').removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

Comment: I almost had the same at first, but didn't work, used the wrong closing brackets... Thank you one problem solved!